# How to Share Mutex, Condition Variable and Queue between two Classes C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

When trying to learn threads most examples suggests that I should put `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable` and `std::queue` global when sharing data between two different threads and it works perfectly fine for simple scenario. However,  in real case scenario and bigger applications this may soon get complicated as I may soon lose track of the global variables and since I am using C++ this does not seem to be an appropriate option (may be I am wrong)

My question is if I have a producer/consumer problem and I want to put both in separate classes, since they will be sharing data I would need to pass them the same `mutex` and `queue` now how do I share these two variables between them without defining it to be global and what is the best practice for creating threads?

Here is a working example of my basic code using global variables.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>

std::queue<int> buffer;
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cond;   

const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 50;

class Producer
{
    public:
        void run(int val) 
        {  
            while(true) {
                std::unique_lock locker(mtx)        ;
                cond.wait(locker, []() {
                return buffer.size() < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
                });

                buffer.push(val);
                std::cout << "Produced " << val << std::endl;
                val --;
                locker.unlock();
            // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
                cond.notify_one();
            }   
        }
};

class Consumer 
{
    public:
        void run()
        {
            while(true) {
                std::unique_lock locker(mtx);
                cond.wait(locker, []() {
                return buffer.size() > 0;
                });

                int val = buffer.front();
                buffer.pop();
                std::cout << "Consumed " << val << std::endl;

                locker.unlock();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                cond.notify_one();
            }
        }
};


int main()
{
    std::thread t1(&Producer::run, Producer(), MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    std::thread t2(&Consumer::run, Consumer());
    


    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you want to have synchronisation objects packaged alongside the resource(s) they are protecting.

A simple way to do that in your case would be a class that contains the buffer, the mutex, and the condition variable. All you really need is to share a reference to one of those to both the Consumer and the Producer.

Here's one way to go about it while keeping most of your code as-is:

```
class Channel {
    std::queue<int> buffer;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cond; 

    // Since we know `Consumer` and `Producer` are the only entities
    // that will ever access  buffer, mtx and cond, it's better to 
    // not provide *any* public (direct or indirect) interface to 
    // them, and use `friend` to grant access.  
    friend class Producer;
    friend class Consumer;
  public:
    // ...
};

class Producer {
  Channel* chan_;
public:
  explicit Producer(Channel* chan) : chan_(chan) {}

  // ...
};

class Consumer {
  Channel* chan_;
public:
  explicit Consumer(Channel* chan) : chan_(chan) {}

  // ...
};

int main() {
  Channel channel;
  
  std::thread t1(&Producer::run, Producer(&channel), MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
  std::thread t2(&Consumer::run, Consumer(&channel));


  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}
```

However, (Thanks for the prompt, @Ext3h) a better way to go about this would be to encapsulate access to the synchronisation objects as well, i.e. keep them hidden in the class. At that point `Channel` becomes what is commonly known as a *Synchronised Queue*

Here's what I'd subjectively consider a nicer-looking implementation of your example code, with a few misc improvements thrown in as well:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <optional>
#include <condition_variable>

template<typename T>
class Channel {
    static constexpr std::size_t default_max_length = 10;
  public:
    using value_type = T;

    explicit Channel(std::size_t max_length = default_max_length)
      : max_length_(max_length) {}

    std::optional<value_type> next() {
        std::unique_lock locker(mtx_);
        cond_.wait(locker, [this]() {
            return !buffer_.empty() || closed_; 
        });
        
        if (buffer_.empty()) {
          assert(closed_);
          return std::nullopt;
        }
        
        value_type val = buffer_.front();
        buffer_.pop();
        cond_.notify_one();
        return val;
    }
    
    void put(value_type val) {
        std::unique_lock locker(mtx_);
        cond_.wait(locker, [this]() {
            return buffer_.size() < max_length_;
        });

        buffer_.push(std::move(val));
        cond_.notify_one();
    }

    void close() {
        std::scoped_lock locker(mtx_);
        closed_ = true;
        cond_.notify_all();
    }

  private:
    std::size_t max_length_;  
    std::queue<value_type> buffer_;
    bool closed_ = false;    

    std::mutex mtx_;
    std::condition_variable cond_; 
};

void producer_main(Channel<int>& chan, int val) {
    // Don't use while(true), it's Undefined Behavior
    while (val >= 0) {
        chan.put(val);
        std::cout << "Produced " << val << std::endl;
        val--;
    }
}

void consumer_main(Channel<int>& chan) {
    bool running = true;
    while (running) {
        auto val = chan.next();
        if (!val) {
            running = false;
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "Consumed " << *val << std::endl;
    };
}

int main()
{
    // You are responsible for ensuring the channel outlives both threads.
    Channel<int> channel;

    std::thread producer_thread(producer_main, std::ref(channel), 13);
    std::thread consumer_thread(consumer_main, std::ref(channel));
    
    producer_thread.join();
    channel.close();

    consumer_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, channels are native in golang now this seems familiar.  Let me try this.

Comment: While going in the right direction, you might want to go one step further and drop the `Producer` and `Consumer` classes all together in this example. Either of these threads becomes a producer or consumer by using the synchronized queue in a specific way, but that doesn't required it to expose a producer or consumer *interface* what the class structure would imply.

Comment: @Frank are you also able to put how the run method would look like in this case? Sorry I am not that much familiar with the friend classes as yet.

Comment: @AftabNaveed it's just a matter of replacing buffer with chan->buffer, etc...  If you are not familiar with that part of the language yet, it's a good exercise.

Comment: Got, I was just wondering how the Friend class would play here, friend class would have allowed access to all private members of the Channel in both Producer and the Consumer but this looks  good too. Thank you.

Comment: @AftabNaveed Yeah, I guess I should have explained that. Since your `Producer` and `Consumer` classes are the only entities that should ever access the members of the class, making everything private and using `friend` to opt both of them in is the way to go. It's a good example of how to use `friend` correctly. I added a comment.

Comment: Shouldn't you unlock the mutex before `notify_one`?